# Simultaneous Feature Selection and Time Series Selection

Tags: feature-selection

I have about 2000 features and 14 times series for them to predict. I am trying to reduce my feature count, but also my time series count. The goal is to find the 30 core features best at predicting the three core time series. I am iteratively cutting, and the process could go something like this:

1. Run feature selection and remove 1500 features (500 left)
2. Remove the 4 time series least well predicted by the remaining 500 features (10 left)
3. Remove 300 features (200 left)
4. Remove 4 time series (6 left)
5. Remove 100 features (100 left)
6. Remove 3 time series (3 left)
7. Select the top 30 features

Is this completely non-sensical for the task of finding which features best predict which time series?
Do I create separate test/train splits for ever iteration?